# past tense after 'in order that'

Tags: tense, idioms

> His group members tried several recipes and prepared all the ingredients in order that they made delicious sandwiches.

Is this sentence idiomatic? I think 'in order that they "could make"' is better than they "made".

The past tense 'made' looks uncomfortable after the phrase 'in order that'.

Comment: Yes. "In order that" is about purpose, so you are looking ahead, not describing a past event. Personally I would simplify: they prepared all the ingredients **to make** the sandwiches.

Comment: No, it isn't idiomatic. If you want to use _in order_, say _in order to make_. But since you are talking about testing recipes, you might say something like _in order that the sandwiches should be especially delicious_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [1] *His group members tried several recipes and prepared all the*
> *ingredients in order that they made delicious sandwiches*.

Generally, "in order" is followed by either a finite *that* clause that contains a modal auxiliary verb, as in [2] or an infinitival clause, as in [3]

> [2] *... *prepared all the ingredients in order that they could make*
> delicious sandwiches*.
>
> [3] ... *prepared all the ingredients in order to make delicious*
> *sandwiches*.